# Oscillator and Power Source Frequency

Tags: microcontroller, crystal, timing

I've been working through a Nixie Clock schematic, to understand how the clocks function as a whole, and am stuck on how timing works for the PIC microcontroller.
The schematic can be found here: http://www.nixieuhren.de/downloads/108b-6.pdf

Why does the microcontroller need both a crystal (in the OSC Pins) and a frequency from the power source (in the T0CKI pin)? Couldn't the microcontroller keep time simply from the oscillator?

Is the frequency from the power source necessary? And if so, why?

Comment: The 60Hz is the time standard. The XTAL merely tells the MCU how fast to provide the state-machine actions.

Comment: I think that the signal power source is used to synchronize switching VFD with AC-power network to avoid flicker.
Flickering occurs when the external lighting and light VFD have different frequencies.
There are open source firmware?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the cost of precision.

All MCUs need a fast clock oscillator so they run, but it doesn't matter what this frequency is, within a wide margin. This means you can use a very cheap, uncalibrated crystal, a ceramic resonator, or if you don't need to hit baud rates, even an RC oscillator. If you used this as the timing source, you would get quite erratic time-keeping behaviour as the temperature changed, and as it aged.

The mains waveform is kept accurate, at no cost to you. As the clock needs a mains power supply (too hungry for batteries), you might as well use that. Note that the actual mains frequency varies a little from f_mains (50 or 60Hz) throughout the day. What is guarranteed is that after n periods of 24 hours, there will have been approximately n*24*3600*f_mains cycles, with the error being non-cummulative. In other words, ideal for a wall clock.

From wikipedia [Utility Frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_frequency#Time_error_correction_.28TEC.29) article

> Today, AC-power network operators regulate the daily average frequency so that clocks stay within a few seconds of correct time. In practice the nominal frequency is raised or lowered by a specific percentage to maintain synchronization. Over the course of a day, the average frequency is maintained at the nominal value within a few hundred parts per million.[19] In the synchronous grid of Continental Europe, the deviation between network phase time and UTC (based on International Atomic Time) is calculated at 08:00 each day in a control center in Switzerland. The target frequency is then adjusted by up to ±0.01 Hz (±0.02%) from 50 Hz as needed, to ensure a long-term frequency average of exactly 50 Hz × 60 sec × 60 min × 24 hours = 4,320,000 cycles per day.[20] In North America, whenever the error exceeds 10 seconds for the east, 3 seconds for Texas, or 2 seconds for the west, a correction of ±0.02 Hz (0.033%) is applied. Time error corrections start and end either on the hour or on the half-hour.[21][22]

Comment: I can see that the frequency tolerance of the delivered mains is tighter than the +/-10% we always designed PSUs for. UK is +/-1% (www2.nationalgrid.com/uk/services/balancing-services/frequency-response/). But where did you get the 'over time it all averages to 0%-ish error' bit from? Thanks, Neil_UK.

Comment: @TonyM It's one of those 'I've always known it, but where's a good citation?' kind of things. I'll race you to one. I'm assuming from your comment that wikipedia doesn't supply a reference.

Comment: I know what you mean on the 'always known it' - good thing is moments likes these make us check them, to see if it's changed over the decades since we learned it :-) I wouldn't take Wikipedia as a definite though, people like us write some of that stuff because 'we've always known'. We ought to be certain you're telling the OP a fact though, have you found an authoratative source? If it's used that commonly for clocks, it should be easy enough to find.

Comment: That snippet has the embedded references in there, 19 to 22, though #20 is 404, I might go in there and edit that.

Comment: @TonyM Fixed up link 20 on wikipedia, but that still only does europe and US, not UK and rest of world. Some continents have trouble keeping the voltage within a factor of two, I wonder how they manage frequency?